# Example of supplying SREG/AX in DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

I can't find any example of supplying SREG/AX extension on Provider (OP) side in DotNetOpenAuth.

All constructors of ClaimsResponse are internal.
Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matthew Johnson, who helped with [the answer](http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/msg/c6c89f5b3cef583c):

> You need a ClaimsRequest first. Then
>   you can generate a ClaimsResponse with
>   ClaimsRequest.CreateResponse();

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.Net MVC, I have:

```
private static OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

var req = openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_identifier"]);
var fields = new ClaimsRequest();                       
fields.Email = DemandLevel.Request;
fields.FullName = DemandLevel.Request;
fields.Nickname = DemandLevel.Request;
req.AddExtension(fields);

// make the request and your response will now contain the fields

var claim = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
string email = null, fullname = null, nickname = null;
if (claim != null)
{
    email = claim.Email;
    fullname = claim.FullName;
    nickname = claim.Nickname;
}
```